# PHP displays only one word from MySQL record in URL variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

A PHP page displays only one word from a MySQL record in a URL variable, while it displays the correct 2 words in the HTML output, I tried many solutions such `'".$row['book_category']."'` and `{$row['book_category']}` etc. but I still get the same one result.

```php
<?php
    foreach($conn->query('SELECT book_category, COUNT(*) FROM books GROUP BY book_category') as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<a href=" . "sidebar_cat_display.php?book_cat=" . $row['book_category'] . ">" . $row['book_category'] . "</a>" . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }
?>
```

So now first `$row` insert is only one word in the url, while the second `$row` outputs two words properly as expected; the problem is I need the two words to be passed as variable in the URL.

Comment: Could you `var_dump()` the `$row['book_category']` variable and provide the results?

Comment: @Skully I got result: string(17) "Short stories"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs cannot have a space character, this is why you are seeing the first word only, you need to encode the value received using [`rawurlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php).

```php
<?php
    foreach($conn->query('SELECT book_category, COUNT(*) FROM books GROUP BY book_category') as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<a href='sidebar_cat_display.php?book_cat=" . rawurlencode($row['book_category']) . "'>" . $row['book_category'] . "</a>" . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }
?>
```

Keep in mind you will also need to adjust the `sidebar_cat_display.php` page to fetch the `book_cat` parameter from the URL accordingly if you aren't already.

Comment: Actually, he just needs to put quotes around the value of the `href` attribute, just like any other attribute with spaces in it.

Comment: @Skully Solved! thank you so much.